# Django Authentication method is not working

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am trying to use the default `Django` from `django.contrib.auth authenticate()` method to authenticate if the user exists. I am doing this right after the user registers. The user registers and their `username`, `email`, and `password` is inputted into the `database` then they are taken to the `login page` but it is not working.

Here is my `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .models import Student
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        fname = request.POST.get('fname')
        lname = request.POST.get('lname')
        pnumber = request.POST.get('pnumber')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        student = Student(fname = fname, lname = lname, pnumber = pnumber, email = email, 
        password = password)
        student.save()
        user = User.objects.create_user(fname, email, password)
        user.save()

    return render(request, ('SignUpPage.html'))

def loginUser(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('mainPage')
        else:
            return render(request, ('LoginPage.html'))
        
    return render(request, ('LoginPage.html'))

def mainPage(request):
    return render(request, ('MainPage.html'))
```

Here is my `urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('login', views.loginUser, name="login"),
    path('mainPage',views.mainPage, name='mainPage')
]
```

Here is my `html` code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Login</title>
<link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,300;1,300&display=swap"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>

<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
  }

  body {
    background-image: url(clean-medical-background_53876-97927.webp);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1920px 975px;
  }

  .wrapper {
    min-height: 90vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: right;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 500px;
  }

  .login_form {
    background: white;
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 400px;
  }

  .login_form .title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #77d5cc;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-weight: 900;
  }

  .form_wrap {
    margin-top: 35px;
  }

  .form_wrap .input_wrap {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .form_wrap .input_wrap:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 10;
  }

  .form_wrap .input_wrap label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
  }
  .form_wrap input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1.3px solid #9597a6;
    padding: 10px;
    outline: none;
  }
  .form_wrap input[type="password"] {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1.3px solid #9597a6;
    padding: 10px;
    outline: none;
  }

  .form_wrap input[type="text"]:focus {
    border-color: #77d5cc;
  }

  .form_wrap input[type="password"]:focus {
    border-color: #77d5cc;
  }

  .form_wrap .login_btn {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background: #77d5cc;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .form_wrap .login_btn:hover {
    background: #bde9e3;
  }

  .form_wrap p {
    font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .form_wrap a {
     
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      width: 30%;
      margin-left: 122px;
      background: #77d5cc;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 0;
      color: white;
      font-size: 15px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
   
  .form_wrap a:hover{
     
     background-color: #bde9e3;

  }   
  
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="login_form">
      <div class="title">
      <label>Login</label>
    </div>

    <form action="/login" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form_wrap">
        <div class="input_wrap">
          <label for="email">Email Address</label>
          <input type="text" name = "email" id="email" />
        </div>

        <div class="input_wrap">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name = "password" id="password" />
        </div>

        <div class="input_wrap">
          <input type="submit" value="Login" class="login_btn" />
        </div>
        <div class="input_wrap">
          <p>Don't Have Account! Sign Up Here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="input_wrap">
          <a href="/" target="_blank">Sign Up</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to redirect your page to login page after a successful registration ?

Comment: Yes that's the idea

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to authenticate with email, basic Django's auth is with username. If you want to use email, you have to tell Django that. Add to your `User` model this:

```
class User(...):
    ...
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    ...
```

Also you said that User registers `username` but in view you uses only `fname` and `lname`. Please be specific and read what you write, otherwise we cannot help you.